# What size should SKScene be?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, autolayout, arkit

When I [don't specify a size for my SKScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66031009/spritekit-sklabelnode-attached-to-aranchor-doesnt-appear-or-appears-fullscreen), I get odd behavior where nodes either don't appear, or they appear in full screen.

One fix is to use Apple's starter code which has a `Scene.sks` and essentially hardcodes the size to something like:

```
sceneView.presentScene(SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 750, height: 1334)))
```

In a world where we have auto layout, different screen sizes, size classes, rotation, etc. it doesn't seem right to hardcode the width and height of a scene.

What's the proper way to specify the SKScene size such that it respects and adapts to my device's dimensions, rotation, etc?

For example, I would ideally be able to omit the size:

```
sceneView.presentScene(SKScene()))
```

... and instead have auto layout resize the scene for me. However, as the linked question shows, this causes the scene to not display properly. Alternatively, if auto layout is not an option, which method(s) should I override to ensure that my scene is always instantiated/updated properly?

I notice that when I choose an incorrect size (e.g. 200x200), it still shows the nodes, but scales them up to be much larger. This leads me to believe that no matter what size I choose, it'll always fill in the camera output output properly (i.e. nothing will be cropped). However, if I choose the wrong size, the artwork would be scaled up/down improperly. Therefore, I now wonder if I should really be basing the size off of the device's dimensions, or rather off of something that the camera gives me (its pixel resolution, for example).

Answer (score 0):

SpriteKit scene size might be set this way:

```
let videoNode = SKVideoNode(fileNamed: "video.mov")
    
let skScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: planeGeo.width * 1280,
                                  height: planeGeo.height * 720))
    
videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: skScene.size.width / 2,
                             y: skScene.size.height / 2)
    
videoNode.size = skScene.size

skScene.addChild(videoNode)
```

Comment: Where does planeGeo get defined?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, Apple has an entire article dedicated to choosing the correct size for a scene: [Scaling a Scene's Content to Fit the View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/scaling_a_scene_s_content_to_fit_the_view)

There are three different strategies they recommend depending on your use-case:

> - Instantiate the scene with a constant size and never change it. Pick a scaling mode that lets the view scale the scene’s content. This gives the scene a predictable coordinate system and frame. You can then base your art assets and gameplay logic on this coordinate system.
> - Adjust the size of the scene in your game. Where necessary, adjust your game logic and art assets to match the scene’s size.
> - Set the scaleMode property to SKSceneScaleMode.resizeFill. SpriteKit automatically resizes the scene so that it always matches the view’s size. Where necessary, adjust your game logic and art assets to match the scene’s size.